# Array creating using specific property of array of objects

Tags: javascript

There is an array of objects as follows.  Need to create an array only using   VatCode propery  from following array of objects without going  through a 'for loop'.
Here  result  should be
resultArray = [1, 15, 25]

```
"Data": [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "VatCode": 1,
        "Name": "Ingen mva.",            
        "VatAccount": {
            "ID": 3,
            "AccountNo": "3190",
            "Name": "Misc Items Income"
        }            
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "VatCode": 15,
        "Name": "Lav mva.",           
        "VatAccount": {
            "ID": 3,
            "AccountNo": "3190",
            "Name": "Misc Items Income"
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "VatCode": 25,
        "Name": "Høy mva.",           
        "VatAccount": {
            "ID": 3,
            "AccountNo": "3190",
            "Name": "Misc Items Income"
        }
    },

]
```

Comment: Congratuations--you have won the special badge for most typos in one question title. By the way, this question has nothing to do with either Angular or JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Data = //your json data    

this.Data.map(data => data.VatCode);
```

> The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   function for every array element.

```js
var data = [
    {
        "Id": 1,
        "VatCode": 1,
        "Name": "Ingen mva.",            
        "VatAccount": {
            "ID": 3,
            "AccountNo": "3190",
            "Name": "Misc Items Income"
        }            
    },
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "VatCode": 15,
        "Name": "Lav mva.",           
        "VatAccount": {
            "ID": 3,
            "AccountNo": "3190",
            "Name": "Misc Items Income"
        }
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "VatCode": 25,
        "Name": "Høy mva.",           
        "VatAccount": {
            "ID": 3,
            "AccountNo": "3190",
            "Name": "Misc Items Income"
        }
    },

];

var s = data.map(data => data.VatCode);
console.log(s);
```